# Symmetric ds system could not found the path specified

Tags: java, symmetricds

I am working on an application for data replication using SymmetricDS. I have set my configuration in both master and slave machines, which are as per the SymmetricDS specifies in its sample example.

But when I install the SymmetricDS it shows "***System could not find the path specified***" in the command prompt.

Please help me in fixing this, as there are few resources about the SymmetricDS issues, I am not able to get the solution anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the **sym_service.bat** file and echoing the paths it is generating, I found that I have set wrong JAVA_HOME environment variable, by terminating it with semicolon ';' character.

I fixed the path for JRE environment.

**$JAVA_HOME=path/to/jre**(when you have installed JRE only) or **path/to/jdk** (if you are interested in development have installed JDK) directory without terminating it by '**;**' because applications that uses $JAVA_HOME appends the directories in their class path. If you put the '**;**' at last the path will be invalid path.

**For Example** :

'***path/to/jdk/home;/bin***' etc. instead of '***path/to/jdk/home/bin***' path.

*Note the semicolon in first path expression.*